# How can I check if my wcf service is using NTLM or Kerberos?

Tags: tcp, network-monitoring, wcf

My WCF service is hosted in IIS and communicates with it's clients via TCP (net.tcp binding), not http. I'm using Microsoft Network Monitor to monitor traffic on the server. I see the Protocol Name is NMF when communicating form client to server, and TCP communicating from server to client. I don't see anywhere in the packet to identify whether it's using NTLM or Kerberos auth. Any ideas?